# Bug in PHP 5.3.10, how do I upgrade without apt?

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt

I have a few Ubuntu boxes that run the newest version of PHP present in the Ubuntu package distributions (PHP 5.3.10). However, [there is a bug in that PHP version that makes my application break](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60817).

Given that the version available in the Ubuntu package repo is broken and I haven't been able to find any kind of time as to when the package will be upgraded, I need to find an alternative.

I am not a very experienced sysadmin, so I am not very comfortable with compiling packages myself. Is there any alternative package repository where I can get PHP 5.3.11+ (preferably PHP 5.3.16)?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 :)

Comment: Does http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-php-5-4-0 help?

Comment: Unfortunately the PHP 5.4 version breaks a whole bunch of dependencies (APC, phpredis, etc.), so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian systems (so my guess on Ubuntu as well since it's also apt) you can install a specific (older) version of a package. [Here](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/03/how-to-install-specific-version-of.html) you can find a nice description on how to do this. The commands used should be the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Ubuntu package repo only contains the 5.3.10 version - nothing earlier than that.

Comment: Another way is to compile a specific version from scratch. Not as easy offcourse.